# Android Studio - Can't specify own minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

After installing the Android L Developer Preview SDK earlier today I wanted to make my app compatible with both Android L and older versions such as Jelly Bean. My app uses a minSdkVersion of 16 but since I tried out the developer preview Android Studio doesn't seem to respect my minSdkVersion. I'm trying to get my app to run on my Galaxy Nexus (API 19) and here's the error I get:

[image]

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simon.holocountownapp"
    android:versionCode="45"
    android:versionName="4.1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="L" />

...
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.2'
    compile 'uk.co.androidalliance:edgeeffectoverride:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:+"
}
```

Comment: Android-Studio is extermely buggy as it is, now you want to install a brand-spanking-new sdk on day 1? You're gonna run into a lot of problems.

Comment: @ChitownDev Android Studio is not the problem. The support libraries in L-preview works with minSdk=L (check their manifest). So if you want to work with minSdk=15 you have to replace this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this dependency:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
```

In this way you are using the **support-v4 in L-preview** (21-rc1).

This support lib is declaring `minSdkVersion L` (you can check the Manifest).

You have to force the minSdkVersion to be 'L' (check the doc: http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

On the development environment, open the build.gradle file for your module and make sure that:

```
compileSdkVersion is set to 'android-L'
minSdkVersion is set to 'L'
targetSdkVersion is set to 'L'
```

It is not a bug, but this is because these APIs are not final. It is a way to prevent installing the apps on a final API 21 device or publishing it on the store using support lib 21-r1.

Answer (score 4):

See my post to /r/AndroidDev [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/) that provides a workaround.

Comment: While this workout works great, a link only answer is strongly discouraged. Please edit the answer to describe the contents.

Answer (score 1):

In developer documentation says (http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html):

> On the development environment, open the build.gradle file for your module and make sure that:
>
> - compileSdkVersion is set to 'android-L'
> - minSdkVersion is set to 'L'
> - targetSdkVersion is set to 'L'

It seems that can't be backward compatible (right now).